# exclusive read locks in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which maintains and assigns portion of input to work on (from a big input table), for multiple instances of a process. The table is organised as follows:

```
BlockInfo Table
---------------
BlockID int primary key
Status  varchar
```

Every process queries for the block of input it should take, and processes that block.

I am expecting the query to be the following:

```
select BlockID 
from BlockInfo 
order by BlockID 
where Status='available' 
limit 1
```

For this effect, I would require that the server maintain *exclusive read locks*, since if the read lock is to be maintained as shared, then multiple instances may get the same block, which causes duplication of efforts and is undesirable.

I could get an exclusive write lock, but not actually write anything. But I want to know if mysql permits an exclusive read lock.

It would also help to hear about alternate ways of implementing this.

Comment: Read locks are shared, they don't block other reads. The only exclusive locks are write locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is:

1. Get an exclusive write lock
2. Select the row you want to process
3. Change its status to "processing" (or something other than "available")
4. Unlock the table
5. Do all your processing of the row
6. Update the row to change its status back to "available"

This will then allow other processes to work on other rows concurrently with this. It keeps the table locked for just enough time to keep them from trying to work on the same row.

Comment: No it can't, because of the exclusive lock in step 1.

Comment: I guess step 1 is a table level lock. If so, how do other processes access the rows concurrently?

Comment: They can access the table after the lock is released in step 4.

Comment: I think multiple processes should not read the table rows concurrently (since if that is done the same block may get allocated to different processes), that is what I am trying to achieve in some sense.

Comment: I think the response given by Barmar should sufficiently solve the problem. The write lock will prevent multiple processes seeing the 'available' status on the appropriate block (all other processes will also try to get the write lock which will be blocked because the previous process is already on it). As soon as one process has identified this block, I will change the status to 'marked' and release the lock. So the next time another process looks for the 'available' status, it wont find the previously referred block in there. Thanks cppcoder and Barmar for your inputs.

Comment: You are right. But this will lead to frequent table locking which may not be good for a high performance application. I have provided an alternate approach in my answer

Comment: They can't get allocated to different processes the way I've written it. Before you release the lock, you mark the row that's being processed as unavailable, so no other process will get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this in the database level, table level lock is the way to go, as mentioned in the other answer. But it will be a bad design, if performance is of concern to your application. This will result in frequent table locking and waiting.

I would suggest you to divide the work inside the application.

Let one process read the available rows from the database and fill the queue of the worker processes who would process them.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a serious performance concern. Could you please comment ? The growth of this block table is sublinear - If the block size is 1000 records, then for every batch of 1000 inputs, one record will be added in this table. If I have 5 million actual inputs, there will be 5000 entries in this table. Secondly, the processing on these inputs will have variable time, so the likelihood of multiple process instances simultaneously looking for the next block of inputs also seems less to me.

Comment: This link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html will explain it better.

Comment: You can choose the solution based on your application. If your table size is small and the frequency with which processes will access it is less, you can go ahead with table lock approach. But if your table is huge and application accesses the table very frequently, better to offload this work division to your application. It would scale better.

Comment: Thank you very much on the insight about performance hits on the solution suggested.